# Norm of a function.

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $f: \mathcal{l}^2 \longrightarrow \mathcal{l}^2$ by $f\big((x_n)\big)=\frac{x_n}{n}$. My question is what is $\|f\|_2$?
My attempt- 
$$
\|f((x_n))\|=\big\|\frac{x_n}{n}\big\| \leq \frac{||x_n||_2}{n}.
$$
I can't get rid of  from $\{n\}$.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a function from $l^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why? This is a question asked in my interview.

Comment: The notation is not appropriate. The $n$ in $f((x_n))$ is a dummy variable serving as the index of the sequence input to $f$. On the other hand, the $n$ in $\frac{x_n}{n}$ is a constant of which the definition of $f$ depends. Therefore, that $n$ doesn't need to go away. The inequality that you have proves that $\|f\|_2\leq\frac{1}{n}$. Evaluating at the sequence that is zero except for a $1$ in position $n$, you get that $\|f\|_2\geq\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @logarithm Fair enough.  There *is* a way to interpret the expression that makes $f$ a function to $\mathbb{R}$.  But it uses the same symbol as a variable on the left and as a constant on the right.  Bad notation, and unless the question was designed to detect if you can recognize bad notation, bad question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, that we have $f((x_n))=( \frac{x_n}{n}).$

Then: $||f((x_n))|| = (\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{|x_k|^2}{k^2})^{1/2} \le (\sum_{k \ge 1}|x_k|^2)^{1/2}= ||(x_n)||.$

Thus $||f|| \le 1.$

If $e_1=(1,0,0,...)$, then $f(e_1)=e_1.$ Now conclude that $||f||=1.$

Comment: So you are interpreting $f$ as a function from $l^2$ to $l^2$, not to $\mathbb{R}$.  That was my first guess too.

Comment: Yes, this is my interpretation.

Comment: First part is okay. $e_1$ is a null sequence. By given definition its image is real number not a sequence.

Comment: @RiteshKhan as has been noted, there is at least one significant problem with the “given definition.”

Comment: Yeah. May be I was wrong.